# Python compatibility issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, cx-oracle

Python is throwing error for some functions that used to run without any issue. I installed pycharm and upgraded some packages on my system.

```
def __init__( self, dbUrl, username, password, use_service_name=False ):
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dbUrl,1521, service_name="TUNET1") if use_service_name else cx_Oracle.makedsn(dbUrl,1521,"TUNET1")
    self.dbConn = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password,  dsn)
```

TypeError: makedsn() takes no keyword arguments

And the following as well in another code.

TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str

Is this some compatibility issue with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was cx_Oracle multiple versions were installed. I removed one and things are back working again.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically impossible to answer from your question.

The error message is telling you that you can't pass in `service_name="TUNET1"`. To figure out what it should be navigate into the `makedsn` method (Navigate -> declaration) and look at the signature.

The second error message is telling you to convert the string you're passing in to unicode.

Are you sure that PyCharm is using the interpreter that you think that is?

Comment: It's not only makedsn(), all of a sudden, a lot of code now don't accept keyword arguments and asks for unicode instead of str.  
The same code used to work before and work on other machines.